# How to select multiple elements on each stride in Tensorflow strided slice?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Tensorflow's strided slice allows to select every n-th element:

```
x = tf.convert_to_tensor([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
x[1::3]
Out[7]: <tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([1, 4, 7], dtype=int32)>
```

How does one select multiple elements on each stride?  E.g., out of every three elements, I want to select elements #1 thru #2, so the result would be:

```
[1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to:

1. "batch up" the data converting the tensor into a N+1-dimensional tensor, where the last dimension represents each window and is the size of the stride (`3` in our example)
2. select the interesting range in that new dimension
3. reshape the tensor back to the original shape

The code would look like so:

```
def multiple_within_stride(x, stride, si, ei):
    """Select x[..., (i * stride + si):(i * stride + ei)] for each i."""
    step1 = tf.reshape(x, (-1, stride))
    step2 = step1[..., si:ei]
    new_shape = list(x.shape)
    new_shape[-1] = -1
    step3 = tf.reshape(step2, new_shape)
    return step3
```

---

Let's consider a simpler version of this code here:

```py
STRIDE_SIZE = 3
FROM = 1
TO = 2
step1 = tf.reshape(x, (-1, STRIDE_SIZE))
step2 = step1[..., FROM:TO+1]
step3 = tf.reshape(step2, (-1,))
```

And here's an excerpt from the `ipython` shell

```py
In [51]: tf.reshape(x, (-1, 3))
Out[51]: 
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 3), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]], dtype=int32)>

In [52]: tf.reshape(x, (-1, 3))[...,1:3]
Out[52]: 
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 2), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[1, 2],
       [4, 5],
       [7, 8]], dtype=int32)>

In [53]: tf.reshape(tf.reshape(x, (-1, 3))[...,1:3], shape=(-1,))
Out[53]: <tf.Tensor: shape=(6,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8], dtype=int32)>
```

One could also use [`tf.shape_to_batch`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/space_to_batch) for that, but it's probably an overkill.